# Replace values of XML child node with values from parent node

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I have an xml file where I want to replace text in a child node with some text from the parent node. Is this possible in notepad++ or do I need to use a different program or to write code?
This is an example xml:

```
<output name="Element_152"">
  <field name="NAME" key="true">Unit001</field>
  <field name="Element">sdf56sd4sdfs54ds</field>
</output>
<output name="Element_153"">
  <field name="NAME" key="true">Unit002</field>
  <field name="Element">s454f6s4fsdf54s</field>
</output>
```

I want to change the value of `<field name="Element">` to the attribute from `<output name=..>`, so I will get:

```
<output name="Element_152"">
  <field name="NAME" key="true">Unit001</field>
  <field name="Element">Element_152</field>
</output>
<output name="Element_153"">
  <field name="NAME" key="true">Unit002</field>
  <field name="Element">Element_153</field>
</output>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the double double quote is a typo and there're no other attributes, this does the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<output name="(\w+)">.+?<field name="Element">\K.+?(?=</field>)`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<output name="              # start tag
(\w+)                       # group 1, 1 or more word character, the name value
">                          # close tag
.+?                         # 1 or more any character, not greedy
<field name="Element">      # literally
\K                          # forget all we have seen until this position
.+?                         # 1 or more any character, not greedy
(?=</field>)                # positive lookahead, make sure we have a closing tag after
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1, tthe value of the name attribute
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Wow!! Thanks for that, it worked like a charm. You just saved me about 500 row edits.